# We are trying to store multiple arrays being inputted through our readPoly function

Tags: c, polynomials

Our Read Poly Function accepts coefficients to each value of X in the polynomial and assigns them their exponents in ascending order. We wish to store multiple polynomials with this function to be used in other functions of the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "functions.c"
//#include "declaration.h"
int maxOrder = 0;
int g=0;
//int numPoly[g];

typedef struct _poly
{
int coeff;
}poly;

int readPoly(int maxOrder)
{
    int j;
    int i;
    poly p[maxOrder];

    for(i=0; i<maxOrder;i++){
    printf("\n Enter the Coefficient of x^(%d):",i);
    scanf("%d",&p[i].coeff);
    }
    printf("\n Your Polynomial:");
    for(j=0;j<(maxOrder)-1;j++){
    printf("%dx^(%d)+", p[j].coeff, j);
    }
    printf("%dx^(%d)\n", p[j].coeff);
    return(maxOrder);
    //g=p;
 }

double main()
{

    int loop = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Hi, Welcome to polynomial-mania a program by Eoghan, Fionn, Ciaran\n") +
        ("What action would you like to take. Please enter a number");
        printf("1. Create a poly\n");
        printf("2. Delete a poly\n");
        printf("3. Add 2 polys\n");
        printf("4. Subtract 2 polys\n");
        printf("5. Multiply 2 polys\n");
        printf("6. Divide one poly by another\n");
        printf("7. Return the order of a polynomial\n");
        printf("8. Normalise a polynomial\n");
        printf("9. Print a polynomial\n");
        printf("10. Test this program\n");
```

Comment: Try to write the function: `int readPoly(Poly *p, int maxOrder)` ... scanf might fails, where do you control this case? ... or you could want use some inputed code to stop the data immission, why not?

Comment: Is there a better way to accept the values for the polynomial to store them this way? If Scanf wouldnt work?  We have to write a testcase too so scanf might not be the best wat

Comment: `double main()` is problematic — it should be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` if you'll process command line arguments.  Your code for `main()` is very incomplete, it would seem.  If your polynomials can be of many different sizes, then you probably need to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`, `free()` et al).  If you've not learned about those yet, life gets trickier — you'll have to place an upper-bound on the size of polynomial and check that you aren't given too many coefficients.